# While Building docker Image if I create other user and try to build I get error at ```npm Install``

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[image]

**While Building docker Image if I create other user and try to build I get error at ```npm Install``**

Comment: Seems like user `app` has no permissions to create a subfolder in `/app`.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this because the default user in your base image owns the `/home` directory and your user `app` does not have access to `write` to `/home`. You can fix this by either:

1. Changing permissions on the `/home` directory (NOT RECOMMENDED)

```
RUN chmod o+w /home
```

2. Or simply change your user *after* you're done installing packages. This will ensure that the default user is used to setup the image before the `app` user is used to run the application.

```
From node:18.6.0-alpine3.16
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
USER app  #<=== doing this after setup is complete
ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This should fix your problem.

And for future, please consider attaching text instead of a screenshot.